# Formula doesn't remain constant after deleting rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm extremely new to working with apps script (just trying to create some queue mechanism)
I have the queue working but I know I want to reset it after every day.

I have some formula for counting the current row that needs attending:

```
=COUNTIF(Responses!$D$2:$D, TRUE)
```

but once I delete my rows my row number is offset by that many rows for example if I deleted 3 rows I'll get `=COUNTIF(Responses!$D5:$D, TRUE).` Is there any way to stop this automatically from happening?

Comment: Kindly add annotated screenshots to describe the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that you can freeze the rows being referenced using INDIRECT so by just making it: `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Responses!$D5:$D"), TRUE)` note the input for INDIRECT is a string